# verify that the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is not a group under multiplication modulo $4$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Given the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$:

-Associativity holds for this set

-Closure holds for this set (constructing the Cayley table, all entries in the tables are in this set).

-there is an identity element $e$ such that $a \cdot e=e \cdot a=a$ (the identity element $e$ is $1$)

-an integer of the set has a multiplicative inverse iff $a$ and $n$ are relative prime.

$\quad 0$ is not relative prime to $n=4$

$\quad 1$ is relative prime to $n=4$

$\quad 2$ is not relative prime

$\quad 3$ is relative prime to $4$

So only $1$ and $3$ has inverse but since not every integer has an inverse, this implies the set does not satisfy the inverse property of the group axiom.
Thus not a group.
Have I gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: Just want to know I have verified correct this set is not a group-it does not satisfy the inverse property of the Group Axiom.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Then it's correct.

Comment: There is one way I would approach this problem a little differently (which is what @StefanHamcke was trying to hint). The best reason that $0$ has no multiplicative inverse is not some abstract principle regarding relative primality, but instead is the concrete fact that $0 \times \text{anything} = 0$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Well, number theoretically, saying that $0$ has no inverse mod $n$ because $0$ and $n$ are coprime, is a valid argument. On the other hand, if one has shown that this set of numbers is a ring under addition and multiplication, then it's indeed the best way to just use this general fact that $0\times k=0$, as you said.